# Python nonnumeric port exception

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I try to send post request with json body with urllib2:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8090/api/', jdata, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

But get exception:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 520, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 439, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 626, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 401, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 419, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1211, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1150, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout) # will parse host:port
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 693, in __init__
    self._set_hostport(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 721, in _set_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '8090��>��hbWb�ba'
```

How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: it should work as is. If you use a non-ascii character encoding in your source file; make sure that the url contains only ascii characters e.g., that you don't use a Unicode slash such as "∕" by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the urllib2 functions doesn't parse right your request. Why don't you try curl?

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://myfavpizzaplace.com/order')
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, 'pizza=Quattro+Stagioni&extra=cheese')
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.perform()
```

example from http://www.angryobjects.com/2011/10/15/http-with-python-pycurl-by-example/